# Notational syntax sugar for list and do notation

Tags: vector, syntax, monads, idris

So I've noticed that in Idris if you define your own list or vector like type — for example the following type I've found to be useful:

```
data HFVec : (f : Type -> Type) -> (n : Nat) -> Vec n Type -> Type where
  Nil : HFVec f Z []
  (::) : (a : f t) -> HFVec f n ts -> HFVec f (S n) (t :: ts)
```

— then you get list syntax for free:

```
test : HFVec List 2 [Int, String]
test = [[3], [""]]
```

I assume this is done when you have a constructor named `::`, but I don't know for certain. In the same way you get do-notation if you have a constructor named `>>=` even if there is no monad implementation:

```
data Test : Type -> Type where
  Pure : a -> Test a
  (>>=) : Test a -> (a -> Test b) -> Test b

test : Test Int
test = do
  Pure 1
  x <- Pure 2
  Pure x
```

This is a pretty cool feature, the only thing is I have not found it documented anywhere. It would be good to know exactly how these mechanisms work so one can know under exactly what circumstances they can be expected to work. Also, are these kind of rules the privilege of the compiler, or can the user make them with the `syntax` and `dsl` features?

Comment: See [here](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#useful-data-types) for the list syntax. The `do`-notation is explained [here](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html?highlight=monad#monads-and-do-notation).

Comment: @AntonTrunov I had read both of these, but had missed in that first link it says "As syntactic sugar, any type with the constructor names Nil and :: can be written in list form." but that doesn't answer my question about how that is achieved. And it doesn't seem to directly mention the requirements for the do sugar in the second link. Is it literally all functions/constructors called `>>=`, no matter what their type?

Comment: Syntactic sugar implies the *parser* simply treats `[1,2,3]` and `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil` as the representing the same thing. The resulting abstract syntax tree (or whatever) makes no distinction regarding how the value was specified in text.

Comment: It would be useful if the Idris documentation had a separate section on built-in syntactic sugars, listing all of them individually, and making it clear what they do and what the pre-requisites are for using them. There's at least three of them: the list notation, the do notation, and (I think) the idiom brackets notation.